# How to compute this matrix derivative?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Assume we have matrix $M$ and

$$ M = A B + C $$

while $M, A, C$ are given. I want to compute $\frac{\partial B}{\partial A}$ and $\frac{\partial B}{\partial C}$. A clear way is to make

$$ B = MA^{-1}-CA^{-1}$$

then differentiate. I am wondering whether there is a more efficient way to do it without computing $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\E{\cal E}
\def\c{\cdot}
\def\l{\left}
\def\r{\right}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\g#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Given
$$\eqalign{
B &= (M-C)A^{-1} \\
}$$
its *differential* with respect to $A$ is the matrix quantity
$$\eqalign{
dB &= (M-C)\;dA^{-1} \\
 &= (M-C)\;\l(-A^{-1}dA\,A^{-1}\r) \\
 &= -B\;dA\;A^{-1} \\
}$$
The *gradient* wrt $A$ is a fourth-order tensor, but its matrix-valued components are
$$\eqalign{
\g{B}{A_{ij}} &= -B E_{ij}A^{-1} \\
}$$
where $E_{ij}$ is a matrix with element $(i,j)$ equal to one and all others equal to zero.

The gradient wrt $C$ can be calculated in a similar fashion.
$$\eqalign{
dB &= -dC\,A^{-1} \\
\g{B}{C_{ij}} &= -E_{ij}\,A^{-1} \\
}$$
And both results can be reformulated to avoid $A^{-1}$
$$\eqalign{
&\l(\g{B}{C_{ij}}\r)A &= -E_{ij} \\
B&\l(\g{B}{C_{ij}}\r) &= \l(\g{B}{A_{ij}}\r) \\
}$$